# this.props is not a function (shallow rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having trouble testing my (legacy) component with jest/enzyme.
It looks like this:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind( this );
    }

    handleSelect( event ) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        this.props[ name ]( value );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <label>
                Dropdown 1{ ' ' }
                <select
                    name="dropdown1"
                    value={ status }
                    data-testid="dropdown-1"
                    onChange={ this.handleSelect }
                >
                    <option value="">Any</option>
                    <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
                    <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
                    <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        );
    }
}
```

**The methods are passed as props!** In this case when the value changes, `handleSelect` will be called and `this.props['dropdown1'](value)` is called.

And my test looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

test( 'select an item from the dropdown', () => {
    const status = wrapper.find( 'select[data-testid="dropdown-1"]' );
    status.simulate( 'change', { target: { value: 'item1' } } );
    expect(status.prop('value')).toEqual('item1');
} );
```

It renders the following error:

```
TypeError: this.props[name] is not a function
```

Dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where do you pass the function down the name prop?

Comment: Bind `handleSelect` function too

Comment: In addition to that, I would generally avoid shallow rendering for interaction tests. Use `mount`.

Comment: Hi, should be export const Button = (props)..not export const Button = ({ props })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are doing unit test instead of integration test.

Normally, you should test the component with mocked function as for best practice, not actual methods from props. And you can also test the props functions in different place where it is defined.

so from your context, you can mock handleSelect with jest.fn() and just test if it is called when you update the dropdown value.

```
   let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
   wrapper.instance().handleSelect = jest.fn();
   .....
   expect(wrapper.instance().handleSelect).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem in your test but in your component. The error is most probably in `this.props[ name ]( value );`, I don't think that is what you want to do. Sometinh like `this.props.save(value)` looks more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your constructor:

```
this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind( this );
```

Since it's not bound, I think it doesn't have access `this.props` from the component.

You should also try to check if it's a defined function before calling it within the `handleSelect`

Comment: Ah, I see. What props are you passing to this component?

Comment: I'm passing several methods to the component corresponding to the name of the dropdown. So in this case `this.props['dropdown1]` is passed and called when the dropdown value changes.

Comment: If you print `this.props['dropdown1']`  within handleSelect, does it give you a function?

Comment: also does it work otherwise, and only fail in the test?